# Python - Problem with continuously opening a file. Permission Error[13]

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that needs to read and write some information from certain files. This is done multiple times over and over again as the program continues. The program can open the files as normal without issues in the beginning, but after a while the program crashes with the error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Player_1.json'

The code that reads the file:

```
def json_read(json_file):
    with open(json_file, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        root = json.load(file)
    file.close()
    return root[0]["Player_Cards"]
```

The code that writes to the file:

```
def json_write(json_file, write):
    with open(json_file, 'r+') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    file.close()

    data[0]["Player_Cards"] = write

    with open(json_file, 'w+') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
```

From what I have heard from other sources, it might be an OS error that limits the amount of times a file can be opened in a timespan. If that is the case how do I fix that error?

Edit:
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: on a side note, you don't need to use `file.close()` anywhere in your code, your file is already being closed by you using a context manager

Comment: Do you open the file somewhere else on your computer? In text editor or something?

Comment: No, the file is not open somewhere else on the computer.

Comment: If it is an OS error, it would be helpful to know which OS you are using.

Comment: The OS I am using is Windows 10.